# How to draw points on the axis with ggplot and classic theme

Tags: r, ggplot2

Using ggplot, I want to draw the projections of the point on the axis (using the "classic" theme). What is the best way to do it? Doing it manually doesn't work because of clipping:

```
  ggplot(data.frame(x=seq(5),y=seq(5)),aes(x=x,y=y))+geom_point() + theme_classic() +   
  scale_x_continuous(limits=c(1,5))  + scale_y_continuous(limits=c(1,5)) + 
  geom_point(aes(x=x,y=0.9),color="red") ## this does not work...
```

Many thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `y = -Inf` to place the points at the bottom of the panel. Combine this with `coord_cartesian(clip = 'off')` to also show the bottom part of the points.

```r
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(data.frame(x=seq(5),y=seq(5)),aes(x=x,y=y))+
  geom_point() + 
  theme_classic() +   
  scale_x_continuous(limits=c(1,5))  + 
  scale_y_continuous(limits=c(1,5)) + 
  geom_point(aes(x=x,y=-Inf),color="red") +
  coord_cartesian(clip = 'off')
```

[image]